# In ANTLR how do I skip the value in a simple expression parser?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Hi there I have been trying to write a simple expression parser, here is the grammar.

```
grammar extremelysimpleexpr ;

stat : expr ;
expr : sub ;
sub : add ( '-' add )* ;
add : VAL ( '+' VAL )* 
    | VAL
    ;  


VAL : [0-9]+ ;
[ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

It matches these expressions

```
1 + 1
0 + 3
4
```

But I do not want it to match single occurrence of `VAL`. I want it to match `1 + 1` but not `4`. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This grammar forces non trivial expressions by syntax:

```
stat : expr ( '+' expr )+
     | expr ( '-' expr )+
     ;

expr : expr ( '+' expr )+
     | expr ( '-' expr )+
     | VAL
     ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to insert predicates, something like this (untested):

```
stat : expr { expr.start != expr.stop }? ;
```

**But don't do this!** That's not a *syntactic* issue, but a *semantic* one. This is something you should validate *after* parsing, unless you want to complicate your grammar for such a little benefit.

Use visitors instead for all your checks.

---

By the way, your grammar assigns different precedence levels to the `-` and `+` operators... I'm not sure this is what you want.

With ANTLR4 you could just write this:

```
expr : '(' expr ')'
     | '-' expr
     | expr ('*'|'/') expr
     | expr ('+'|'-') expr
     | VAL
     ;
```

Comment: Is this not a syntactic issue ? because by language definition, I am disallowing `VAL`  as `expr`. `1` is not an `expr`.

Comment: Is it not possible to have some sort of negative lookahead here ?

Comment: You can put any code you want inside the `{`...`}?` predicate. And you have access to the token stream so you can construct lookaheads/lookbehinds - you just have to use code to express them. I'm just saying using a visitor would be a better/cleaner approach.